# Find a function given a limit

Tags: limits, functions

I'm coding some algorithms, but I need help to find a function.
Let' suppose these 3 functions:

$$c(x)=1-g(x)$$

$$r_1(x)=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2^{\left(x-1\right)}}$$

$$r_2(x)\ =\ \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2^{\left(x-1\right)}}\cdot g(x)$$

$$d(x)=\frac{r_1(x)+r_2(x)}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{c(x)}$$

My need is to find the function g that allows

$$lim_{x\to\infty}d(x)=1$$

(or at least, as close as possible to 1).

My constraints:

> - Being quickly close to the limit
> - $for\ x\in[1; 128],\   g(x) \in [0; 1[$

I put all these functions in a graph for clarity:
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/dgkmwtgis8

My level in mathematics in not very good, so for now I just try to adapt the following functions:
$$g_1=\sqrt{\frac{2^x-1}{2^x}}$$
$$g_2\ =\frac{2^x-1}{2^x}$$

g1 works for my code, but d(x) is too far from 1.

Thank you for any help you could provide !

Comment: Do you mean that $d(x)=\frac{r_1(x)+r_2(x)}{2c(x)}$, and do you want $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} d(x) = 1$?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I wasn't sure how to write that. I will edit my post accordingly.

Comment: I find some function $g(x)=\frac{2^x -\sqrt{2}}{2^x + \sqrt{2}}$. when applying this $g$ at desmos calculator you made above, the $d(x)$ is identical to $1$. Please check it. And because the process to get this $g$ is a bit tedious calculation, I skipped it to write down. However If you need it, please ask me for it.

Comment: This solution seems perfect to me ! Thank you very, very much!

Comment: You should copy this equation into an answer. At least I should give you a vote :D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we assume $g(x)=\frac{2^x -\sqrt{2}}{2^x + \sqrt{2}}$, then $d(x)$ is identical to $1$.